# How can I extract an integer from within a string?

Tags: c, string-parsing

I'm working on an assignment and as part of it I need to extract the integer from a string.

I've tried using the `atoi()` function, but it always returns a `0`, so then I switched up to `strtol()`, but it still returns a `0`.

The goal is to extract the integers from the string and pass them as arguments to a different function. I'm using a function that then uses these values to update some data (`update_stats`).

Please keep in mind that I'm fairly new to programming in the C language, but this was my attempt:

```
void get_number (char str[]) {
    char *end;
    int num;
    num = strtol(str, &end, 10);
    update_stats(num);
    num = strtol(end, &end, 10);
    update_stats(num);
}
```

The purpose of this is in a string `"e5 d8"` (for example) I would extract the `5` and the `8` from that string.

The format of the string is always the same.

How can I do this?

Comment: There's no obvious bug in this part of the code, so the problem can't be reproduced.

Comment: You could use loops to skip over all non-digit characters using `isdigit` before you use `strtol`

Comment: Both `atoi` and `strtol` expect to receive the pointer to the first character of a numeral—your pointer must already be pointing to a digit. Neither “e” nor “d” is a digit when the base is 10. To find the numerals in the string, you should write code to examine each character to determine whether it is a digit or not. Once you have found a digit, you can convert either it (just the one digit) or the sequence of digits (several digits) there to a number, depending on what your need is.

Comment: @Lundin: There is a perfectly obvious bug; passing a pointer to the first character of `"e5 d8"` to `strtol` is not a correct way to find the “5” and convert it to a number.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Indeed, if that is the actual input. Hard to tell without the calling code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`strtol` doesn't *find* a number in a string. It converts the number *at the beginning of the string*. (It does skip whitespace, but nothing else.)

If you need to find where a number starts, you can use something like:

```
const char* nump = strpbrk(str, "0123456789");
if (nump == NULL) /* No number, handle error*/
```

([`man strpbrk`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strpbrk.3.html))

If your numbers might be signed, you'll need something a bit more sophisticated. One way is to do the above and then back up one character if the previous character is `-`. But watch out for the beginning of the string:

```
if ( nump != str && nump[-1] == '-') --nump;
```

Just putting `-` into the `strpbrk` argument would produce false matches on input like `non-numeric7`.

Answer (score 1):

If the format is always like this, then this could also work

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *str[] = {"a5 d8", "fe55 eec2", "a5 abc111"};
    int num1, num2;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      sscanf(str[i], "%*[^0-9]%d%*[^0-9]%d", &num1, &num2);
      printf("num1: %d, num2: %d\n", num1, num2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
num1: 5, num2: 8                                                                                                                                                                   
num1: 55, num2: 2                                                                                                                                                                  
num1: 5, num2: 111
```

`%[^0-9]` will match any non digit character. By adding the `*` like this `%*[^0-9]` indicates that the data is to be read from the string, but ignored.

Comment: Nice use of `sscanf`. I really appreciate the effort. However, it's nowhere specified that the format is the way you have taken for granted. Try to add a little more genericity if you can. Also, if the user is stuck in I/O and string to integer conversion, there's a high probability, that he/she's new. So, it would be really helpful to add or at least provide a link to the documentation, e.g., in this case, `sscanf`. Nice answer though :)

Comment: Well thanks. But also note that the question say "The format of the string is always the same.", which implies this could be the same. Genericity is a good thing, but the absence of it let solution works like this. The very first hit on google for `sscanf` is the documentation. I think what really be improvment here is little explanation of the format, which I may add here.

Comment: Yep true. Sorry. I guess I missed the last statement. Nice answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write the logic on your own. I know, it's like *reinventing the wheel*, but in that case, you will have an insight into how the library functions actually work.

Here is a function I propose:

```
bool getNumber(str,num_ptr)
char* str;
long* num_ptr;
{
    bool flag = false;
    int i = 0;
    *num_ptr = 0;
    char ch = ' ';
    while (ch != '\0') {
        ch = *(str + i);
        if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
            *num_ptr = (*num_ptr) * 10 + (long)(ch - 48);
             flag = true;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Don't forget to pass a string with a `\0` at the end :)

Comment: This function scans the whole string and returns a number consisting of the digits in order.

Comment: considering `c`, you may convert bool to int and `true` and `false` to `1` and `0` respectively